# Two options to update a TextView of an Activity from another class via TimerTask

Tags: java, android, android-activity, textview, timertask

First of all thank you for the good work. The forum was always a good help for me but this time I need to ask a specific question.

I created a class Tasks which shall update a `TextView` every second in the `BatteryStatus` Activity. I found out that there are two options to update the text:

1. Pass reference to a Context interface
2. Make a getter function in the activity class

For solution 1 I get this error:

```
09-30 20:08:29.635: W/System.err(14515): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException:      Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

For solution 2 this error comes up:

```
09-30 21:23:07.110: W/System.err(16344): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 21:23:07.110: W/System.err(16344): at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1653)
```

Ok, the program doesn't know where and what this TextView is.
What do I need to change to make it work? 
I really want to understand both ways to update TextViews,Buttons... in another class.

1. Pass reference to a Context interface:

   ```
   public class BatteryStatus extends Activity{

       private static Timer myclock;
       private static TimerTask mytask;
       TextView tvBatteryStatus;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_battery_status);   // XML-Datei im Layout - Ordner

           // Text View
           tvBatteryStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBatteryStatus);

           // Timer Task
           myclock = new Timer();
           mytask = new Tasks(BatteryStatus.this);
           // schedule the task to run every 1000ms and delay execution for another 1000ms
           myclock.scheduleAtFixedRate(mytask, 1000, 1000);

       }
   }
   ```

   Tasks

   ```
   public class Tasks extends TimerTask  {

       Context context;

       public Tasks(Context context){this.context = context;}

       public void run(){      
           try{Update();}
           catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
       }

       public void Update(){
           TextView txtView = (TextView) ((BatteryStatus)context).findViewById(R.id.tvBatteryStatus);
           txtView.setText("Hello");
       }

   }
   ```
2. Make a getter function in the activity class

BatteryStatus with getter

```
    public class BatteryStatus extends Activity{

        private static Timer myclock;
        private static TimerTask mytask;
        TextView tvBatteryStatus;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_battery_status);   // XML-Datei im Layout - Ordner

            // Text View
            tvBatteryStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBatteryStatus);

            // Timer Task
            myclock = new Timer();
            mytask = new Tasks();
            // schedule the task to run every 1000ms and delay execution for another 1000ms
            myclock.scheduleAtFixedRate(mytask, 1000, 1000);

        }

        public TextView getTextView(){
            TextView tV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvBatteryStatus);
            return tV;
        }

    }
```

Tasks

```
    public class Tasks extends TimerTask  {

        TextView t;
        BatteryStatus b = new BatteryStatus();

        public void run(){      
            try{Update();}
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        public void Update(){
            t = b.getTextView();
            t.setText("hellooo");
        }

    }
```

Comment: pass the reference of the textView, and update the text using runOnUiThread()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic thumb rule in android is that you can update the views only on the main thread, thus you get the exception

```
 09-30 20:08:29.635: W/System.err(14515): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException:      Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Which tells that you are accessing the view elements from non UI thread. So in order to make changes to view from non UI thread, refer to this website and read the thread section. Its all you need..
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty solution:

Edit the Tasks class:

```
    public class Tasks extends TimerTask  {

        TextView t;
        Activity activity;
        BatteryStatus b = new BatteryStatus();

        public void run(){      
            try{Update();}
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        public void Update(){
            if(activity != null){
                activity.runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
                    t = b.getTextView();
                    t.setText("hellooo");
                });
            }            
        }
        public void setActivity(Activity a){ // this must be called from the rest of your application
            activity = a;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With the second approach you are instantiating a new Activity, not using the one that has been initialized the TextView. You must supply in the constructor a reference for the activity.

```
    public Tasks(BatteryStatus b){this.b = b;}
```

And you can use safety the textView.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem you are facing in Second Solution in **Make a getter function in the activity class**

You have to pass the Context reference via constructor.

```
 public class Tasks extends TimerTask  {

        TextView t;
        BatteryStatus b = new BatteryStatus();

         Context context;
         public Tasks (Context context){
         this.context=context;}

        public void run(){      
            try{Update();}
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        public void Update(){
             TextView txtView = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.tvBatteryStatus);
              txtView.setText("Hello");
        }

    }
```

and in this class make Tasks object and pass the context of this BatteryStatus activity to Tasks.class

```
 public class BatteryStatus extends Activity{

        private static Timer myclock;
        private static TimerTask mytask;
        TextView tvBatteryStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_battery_status);   // XML-Datei im Layout - Ordner

        // Text View
        tvBatteryStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBatteryStatus);

        // Timer Task
        myclock = new Timer();
        mytask = new Tasks();
        // schedule the task to run every 1000ms and delay execution for another 1000ms
        myclock.scheduleAtFixedRate(mytask, 1000, 1000);
        // make an object and pass the reference of this activity
        Tasks abc = new Tasks(BatteryStatus .this);
    }



}
```